# HP Pavilion display error Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, display, radeon, hp-pavilion

I just installed Xubuntu 20.04 in my new PC, but I have a problem when setting my Display at 1366x768. When I set it, I get my screen like in the image. I have to use it at 1280x720. I'm trying to use Xubuntu, because I have a problem in Ubuntu, because sometimes my screen turns back before starting.

[image: Xubuntu screen error at default resolution]

Comment: Could you share the output of `sudo lshw -C video`? This will contain information about which video driver you’re using. With this, it might be easier to offer a better solution 

Comment: Yes. It says:
  *-display                 
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Picasso
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versión: c2
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       recursos: irq:54 memoria:e0000000-efffffff memoria:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memoria:fe700000-fe77ffff memoria:c0000-dffff
Thank you.